# Проверить нет ли записей для строки согласно периоду дат в другой таблице для этого периода дат

Tags: oracle, plsql

Прошу помочь в решении запроса: есть 2 таблицы - ORDER (заказы по товарам) и PROMO (акции по товарам). Есть такой пример, где мы можем проверить не попадает ли товар на день заказа в акцию:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PROMO A, ORDER F
 WHERE AND A.ITEM = F.ITEM AND A.STORE = F.STORE AND
  F.ORDERDATE BETWEEN A.PROMODDEB AND A.PROMOFIN;
```

Но надо сделать более широкую проверку, у заказа есть период который он покрывает, образно я заказываю  02.02.23 на продажи до 09.02.23 (F.ORDERCOVER). Соответственно хочу проверить нет ли в этот период дат хоть одной акции для товара (BETWEEN A.PROMODDEB AND A.PROMOFIN), то есть для любой даты из диапазона дат между F.ORDERDATE и F.ORDERCOVER, а не только по F.ORDERDATE, как в запросе примере.

Comment: Диапазоны пересекаются, если любое начало интервала меньше конца другого интервала.

Comment: Приведите пример исходных данных и желаемый результат выборки